# How to do Cross Product of 1x5 vectors?

Tags: vectors, 3d, cross-product

The following question asks for both the dot product and cross product of the two vectors. The dot product was fine to find, however, when it comes to the cross products I can only find examples and solutions for ones with a base or row of 3, representing x y z. How is it possible to calculate the cross product between two 1x5's?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Math question]

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, good question. I think you should ask the source.

Comment: It's a good idea to understand that the cross product is **only** defined for three-dimensional vectors. Not two, not four, not five ... Only three.

Comment: @MattiP. Yea that's what I thought so I was very confused when this was asked

Comment: The closest thing you can calculate is the *outer product* $a\land b$.